# How do I windows shared folders in my bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to access a windows shared folder from my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Please forgive my ignorance in advance, I am very new with dockers and pipelines and bitbucket, etc...

I mounted a windows shared folder into a my host instance using

`mount -t cifs //fileshare /mnt -o username=THEUSERNAME,password=THEPASSWORD`

and this works fine

and I ran bitbucket runners using

`docker container run  -it --privileged -d -v /tmp:/tmp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /mnt:/mnt...`

and this works, if I went into the container using docker exec, I can ls /mnt and see everything.

However, if I run my pipelines with this step

`script: - ls /mnt`

I get ls: cannot access '/mnt': No such file or directory

I've also tried mounting the drives from pipeline level, but I cant seem to figure out how to run the pipeline as privileged, or cap-add SYS_ADMIN and DAC_READ_SEARCH